# Oracle - SET ROLE Statement

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, user-roles, role

The bellow code not working in java.

```
Class.forName('oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver');
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection('jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:test', 'xyz', 'pass');
            PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement("set role ? identified by ?");
            String role = "TEST_ROLE";
            String pswd = "TEST_PASS";
            stmt.setString(1, role);
            stmt.setString(2, pswd);
            stmt.execute();
```

And the above code throws an exception:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01937: missing or invalid role name
```

I tried same role and password from command mode it successfully executed.

Comment: A role name is an identifier. You can't pass an identifier as a parameter in a prepared statement.

Comment: Try concatenating the params to SQL instead and executing?

Comment: @GurV, I have code with concatenating the params right now. but in the logger it prints the password. i need to avoid showing the password in logger.

Comment: @user3515080: in that case you have to modify the logger.

Answer (score 0):

You can only use PreparedStatement's bind variables to bind **values**, not identifiers such as role names or their passwords. You'd have to resort to string manipulation to get this effect (assuming the values aren't hardcoded, as shown above, in which case you can just put in them in the string an be done with it). E.g.:

```
String role = "TEST_ROLE";
String pswd = "TEST_PASS";
String sql = String.format("set role %s identified by %s", role, pswd);
```

Comment: I have code with concatenating the params right now. but in the logger it prints the password. i need to avoid showing the password in logger.